# How to convert Java 17 record to Clojure map?

Tags: clojure, java-17, java-record

There is a standard function `clojure.core/bean` converting POJO to map:

```
class MyPojo{
  public String getFirst(){ return "abc"; }
  public int getSecond(){ return 15; }
}

IFn bean = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "bean")

var result = bean.invoke(new MyPojo())

// result => {:first = abc, :second = 15}
```

For Java 17 record classes this function would not work, because records do not follow POJO convention `"get***"` for properties.

Is there Clojure support for Java 17 record instances in the same manner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 16 introduces [`Class.getRecordComponents`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getRecordComponents()). So given an instance of a record, you can look up the record's class, and from there its record components. Each record component has a name and a getter Method, which you can use to look up the value of that component. You can put these pieces together to build an analogue of `bean`.

```
(defn record->map [r]
  (into {} (for [^java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent c (seq (.getRecordComponents (class r)))]
             [(keyword (.getName c))
              (.invoke (.getAccessor c) r nil)])))
```

Comment: ech this is likely to be slow though?

Comment: If performance mattered you wouldn't be beaning up an unknown record. But of course, time things so you can see if they're fast enough for a specific use case.